# Do browsers handle virtualization on scrollable areas?

Tags: javascript, browser, virtualization

Do any browsers properly handle data virtualization in any way? By virtualization i mean do any browsers handle the insertion of objects and memory management in such a way that only the visible objects in a scroll area are rendered / optimized usage of memory.

Consider the following simplified example:

http://jsbin.com/OsUduSE/1/

What sort of optimizations will newer browsers do on this when rendering?

I know components like https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid do some code to actually not load elements in view but what I am wondering is if in newer browsers this sort of optimization is necessary for simple large lists?

Comment: i know most browsers cheat/optimize when the tab is not visible. requestAnimationFrame helps these kinds of optimization as well.  i've seemed to have "caught" chrome skimping on renders "under the fold", but i don't have any link or evidence other than observation.